# The Location Services authorization dialog leads to app being deactivated?

Tags: ios, core-location

I noticed that when my app displays the Location Services authorization dialog, the app gets suspended for a short while (it receives the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification). Is this documented or discussed somewhere? What could be the reason? Do other authorization dialogs also do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m still interested in some authoritative resources on this, but after some thinking the behaviour makes sense. The authorization dialog can’t be a part of the app, since that could create a security risk: the app could try to confirm the dialog on user’s behalf. And since the dialog is not a part of the app, it makes sense to consider the app deactivated while the pop-up is being displayed. It looks like all authorization dialogs do it.